# Boundary of the sphere (Differential forms)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I have this problem from an example in "D.Bachman,A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms".
Suppose:
$$\phi_1(r,\theta)=(r\cos 2\pi\theta,r\sin2\pi\theta,\sqrt{1-r^2})  $$
$$\phi_2(r,\theta)=(-r\cos 2\pi\theta,r\sin2\pi\theta,-\sqrt{1-r^2})$$
Let $\sigma_1=Im(\phi_1)$, $\sigma_2=Im(\phi_2)$, then $\sigma=\sigma_1+\sigma_2$ is a unit shpere in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Show that: $\partial\sigma=\emptyset$
My solution is:
First we have:
\begin{align*} 
\partial\sigma_1&=(\phi_1(1,\theta)-\phi_1(0,\theta)-(\phi_1(r,1)-\phi_1(r,0) )  \\ 
&= (\cos2\pi\theta,\sin2\pi\theta,0)-(0,0,1)-(r,0,\sqrt{1-r^2})+(r,0,\sqrt{1-r^2})\\
&=(\cos2\pi\theta,\sin2\pi\theta,0)-(0,0,1)
\end{align*}
And:
\begin{align*} 
\partial\sigma_2&=(\phi_2(1,\theta)-\phi_2(0,\theta)-(\phi_2(r,1)-\phi_2(r,0) )  \\ 
&= (-cos2\pi\theta,\sin 2\pi\theta,0)-(0,0,-1)-(r,0,-\sqrt{1-r^2})+(r,0,-\sqrt{1-r^2})\\
&=(-\cos2\pi\theta,\sin2\pi\theta,0)-(0,0,-1)
\end{align*}
Therefore:
\begin{align*} 
\partial\sigma&=\partial \sigma_1+\partial \sigma_2\\
&=(\cos2\pi\theta,\sin 2\pi\theta,0)-(0,0,1)+(-\cos2\pi\theta,\sin 2\pi\theta,0)-(0,0,-1)
\end{align*}
I don't see how can $\partial \sigma=\emptyset$.
But when I use a parameterization of $\sigma$ (a unit shpere), that is:
$$\phi(\varphi,\theta)=(\cos(2\pi \varphi) \cos(\pi\theta),\sin(2\pi \varphi) \cos(\pi\theta),\sin (\pi\theta))$$
It can easily lead straight to $\partial\sigma=\emptyset$
I am really confused about this.

Here are some previous definitions from the book:
**Definition 1:** Let $I=[0,1]$, a n-cell,$\sigma$, is the image of a differentable map, $\phi:I^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$, with a specified orientation. We denote the same cell
opposite orientation as $-\sigma$. We define a $0$-cell to be a oriented point of $\mathbb{R}^m$ 
**Definition 2:** A $n$-chain is a formal linear combination of $n$-cells, and we assume the following relation holds:
$$\sigma-\sigma=\emptyset$$
$$\sigma+\tau=\tau+\sigma$$
$$(m+n)\sigma=m\sigma+n\sigma$$
**Definition 3:** Let a $n$-cell $\sigma$ is the image of the parameterization $\varphi:I^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ with the induced orientation, we define the boudary of $\sigma$ (denoted as $\partial \sigma$) as:
$$\partial \sigma=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1}(\phi|_{(x_1,...,x_{i-1},1,x_{i+1},...x_n)}-\phi|_{(x_1,...,x_{i-1},0,x_{i+1},...x_n)})$$
**Definition 4:** Let $C=\sum n_i\sigma_i$ is a $n$-chain, we define the boundary of $C$ as:
$$\partial C=\sum n_i\partial \sigma_i$$
**Notes:** The book intially lets both $r,\theta$ on above problem vary from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: First, I don't like your notation. When you write $\phi(1,\theta)$, you mean the curve given by $\phi(1,\theta)$ as $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $2\pi$. ... At any rate, you have the same issue with spherical coordinates — the poles show up in the boundary because the coordinate system degenerates there, just as the polar coordinate system degenerates at the origin. Just work out the case of a disk in the plane, and you're going to have the same problem. If you pull back forms to integrate it'll be OK. Please edit with a precise statement of Bachman's $\partial\sigma$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. I have edited some definitions from the book so that you can understand more about my problem.

Comment: As I suspected, the degeneration of these $2$-cells, in all three examples make the statements incorrect.

Comment: @TedShirin could you please be more specific about this? I'm having hard time understanding these concepts. Thank you!

Comment: Work out the $2$-cell as I suggested for the unit disk. Your calculation is correct. The book is wrong.

Comment: Oh i got it, many thanks sir @TedShifrin!